# How to store custom object that can't be modified into UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am building a game that uses a framework that has a deep learning bot in it. I can access the bot using a class called GameSession(), in order to make it work, I need to send it my move gameSession.userPlay(x) and then ask it to do its move (gameSession.move()). The issue is that I do not have access to the current state of the game that I can save and use as persistence, I can't modify this class since it's a framework to make it codable.

So basically, I want to store the gameSession() object into userdefaults somehow since that is the only way I can achieve persistence when app is closed. If I just store the state of the screen that I have and can store then when I load the app back again, the bot won't go to that state since its actions cannot be predicted. As in, it can do two different responses for the same action.

Here's how it basically works as a Chess game:

1. I create session,
2. I let user pick their move -> pass this data to the session so the bot knows what the user did,
3. I get the response move from bot and then use the bots action to change update the game.

Now I want to be able to close the app after a few moves and load it back in. I used to make objects codable but this I can't modify, if I make another class that implements codable and then has the session as an object, I can't encode and decode this special object.

Would anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually what these frameworks do is this: the object in question either is serializable with NSCoding or it hands you, on request, some state-holding object that is serializable with NSCoding. You can then archive and restore that. So look through the API for an object type that says NSCoding somewhere.

I say NSCoding because that is the long-standing Objective C basis of serialization. Codable is Swift and is fairly new.

Either way, your goal is convert state into a Data / NSData object, because that's the sort of thing you can store on disk or in user preferences. (Possibly the framework's API actually does this for you and hands you the Data object directly; look for that too.)

If this framework has no such feature, you cannot maintain state between launches and you shouldn’t use this framework, as it is unsuitable for iOS.

Comment: Damn, thank you. It was a class assignment with the bot provided by the professor. I guess there is no way I can do this then.

Comment: Well, it sounds to me like the framework is just a toy — an example for purposes of a specific exercise. I presume you are not expected to maintain state between launches as part of that exercise.

Comment: It's a part of the assignment, but all of our iOS assignments have had generally the same structure so maybe he forgot to remove this as a requirement. I'll email him and ask. Thank you!

Comment: That's a great idea. Maybe he'll insist that you _can_ serialize the state, and that will be a hint that there really is something vended by the framework that adopts Codable or NSCoding that you've failed to notice. Or maybe the framework dispenses a Data / NSData object for this very purpose, but again, you'd need to look for it in the API.

Comment: I did look in there and there doesn't seem to be anything. This is the api that I can access, https://imgur.com/Pk97Q6X there doesn't seem to be anything I can serialise.

Comment: Well, every single one of those GameSession properties is a `var`. And they are all Codable types. So you can copy them all off into a struct, encode the struct, decode the struct, make a new GameSession, and set all of those values. I don't know whether that would result in the same internal state, though.

Comment: Oh, I'll try that, thank you so much! Thanks for the good work with your books too!